# Embed keeps adding the same fields. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some commands like user-info in a command handler, here is my code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Uembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
const randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1;
const moment = require("./IGNORE/moment.min.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "user-info",
  description: "Shows info about a user.",
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.deletable) message.delete();
    Uembed.setTitle(`${message.author.tag}'s information. `);
    Uembed.setColor(randomcolor);
    Uembed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL());
    Uembed.setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL());
    Uembed.setFooter(
      `Requested by : ${message.author.tag}`,
      message.author.displayAvatarURL()
    );
    Uembed.addFields(
      { name: `Username:`, value: `${message.author.username}`, inline: true },
      { name: `Tag:`, value: `${message.author.discriminator}`, inline: true },
      { name: `ID:`, value: `${message.author.id}` },
      { name: `Last message:`, value: `${message.author.lastMessage + 1}` },
      {
        name: `Joined this server:`,
        value: `${moment(message.member.joinedAt).format(
          "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"
        )}`,
      },
      {
        name: `Account created:`,
        value: `${moment(message.author.createdAt).format(
          "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"
        )}`,
      }
    );

    message.channel.send(Uembed).then((m) => m.delete({ timeout: 60000 }));
  },
};
```

I already tried to put it out of the execute function, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what gets sent?

Comment: @Lioness100 [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XFdmTsG7633hT9H6AcNo_-UCcfGNenN/view?usp=sharing), i provided video with result + what the bug is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! You just need to put this code after the `Message.send()`.

```
Uembed.fields = [];
```

It sets the embed fields to an empty array, so it kind of resets the embed fields.